# derivative and curl vector notational difference

Tags: notation, vectors

This must be a really trivial question, and I am not sure I am allowed to post these here. Just wanted to know but didn't know what to search.
What is the difference between $\overrightarrow {dr}$ and d$\overrightarrow r$?

Also, is del a vector? Should a curl be written as $\overrightarrow \nabla \times  \overrightarrow A$ or $\nabla \times \overrightarrow A$?

Books have different notations so I am quite confused.

Thanks,

Comment: del is not a vector - it is a vector operator.

Comment: ∇×A⃗          is correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del